# How to force page into amp cache?

Tags: amp-html

I have posted an example AMP page onto a heroku project;

http://boiling-garden-78683.herokuapp.com

I have then tried to use the following curl command to get the AMP cache URL:

```
curl -i -s -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Goog-Api-Key:<MYKEY>" -d "{urls: ['http://boiling-garden-78683.herokuapp.com/']}" "https://acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com/v1/ampUrls:batchGet"
```

This curl command is returning:

```
{
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "http://boiling-garden-78683.herokuapp.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I not understanding about AMP? Isn't the whole purpose of making an AMP page so that I can get an AMP URL to give to users instead of them having to go to my site directly?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Wait when will google crawler find your pages changes
2. Just do this call by "curl" or just go the link using browser:

   curl https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/c/s/boiling-garden-78683.herokuapp.com

Then the API call you provided will return what you want ;)
Mechanism of updating AMP cache (or if not in cache it will add if your AMP is valid) is described on this 
[Update AMP Content](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly construct the AMP Cache URL. The logic is pretty simple: remove the protocol (`http://` in this case), and prefix `https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/`. If your page is served from https, you would use `https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/`.

But yes, the API you are using only returns results that have **already** been cached. You can prime the cache with the `update-ping` URL that Nick provided and then it should work.